# Grab value of array, in array, with for each

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have the following array:

```
print_r($all_projects);
--------------------------------
Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
                     [pro_id] => 7 
                     [0] => 7 
                    ) 
       [1] => Array ( 
                     [pro_id] => 20 
                     [0] => 20 
                     ) 
)
```

How do I grab each `pro_id` in a foreach loop?
I can find quite a bit information online on how to create an array, and how to grab the key and value from an array. But I have difficulty grabbing the value of a key in an array, in an array.

I currently have this for each:

```
foreach ($all_projects as $project => $project_id){ 
echo $project_id;
}
```

Which in turn returns the following:

```
Array
Array
```

This makes sense to me, but how do I go [deeper](http://i.qkme.me/3uzx0y.jpg) in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
foreach ($all_projects as $project => $project_id){ 
  echo $project_id['pro_id'];
}
```

or even cleaner to read :

```
foreach ($all_projects as $project){ 
  echo $project['pro_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($all_projects as $project) {
    echo $project['pro_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($all_projects as $KEY => $VALUE) {
  echo "KEY: $KEY - PRO_ID: {$VALUE['pro_id']}";
}
```

In your case, you'd want:

```
foreach ($all_projects as $project_id => $project) { 
  echo $project_id . " = " . $project['pro_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now with PHP5.5, you have an easy way to do it:

```
foreach ($all_projects as list($id))
    echo $id;
```

And the old way:

```
foreach ($all_projects as $project)
    echo $project['pro_id'];
```

Hope it'll help you!

Answer (score 0):

If we're looping through the `$all_projects` with `foreach` loop this way,

```
foreach ($all_projects as $key => $project) {
    echo($key);
}
```

then `$key` will actually be 0, 1, etc., not 7 or 20 -- as you might intended this to be -- and `$project` will be the content of the project.

In your case, I presume that the "project id" you desired are stored inside the "project" array itself, so as other suggested, you should write something like

```
foreach($all_projects as $project) { // omitting the $key part since you don't need it
    echo($project['pro_id']);
}
```

this will print the actual "project id", which is the `pro_id` that you want.

If you were to improve this code, you might want to restructure your `$all_projects` this way

```
$all_projects = array();
$all_project[7] = $some_project; // your first project with id 7
$all_project[20] = $some_other_project; // your second project with id 20
```

then you will be able to use your original code to loop through:

```
foreach($all_projects as $project_id => $project) {
    echo($project_id);
}
```

with `$project_id` be 7, 20, etc., and `$project` be the content of your project.

Hope this answers your question!